How do you find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a symmetrical 4 x 4 matrix
I have the following 4 x 4 matrix
$$ 
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&1&0\\ 
0&1&0&0\\ 
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I want to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix. Which means I have to find
$$
\det\left( 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&1&0\\ 
0&1&0&0\\ 
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix} 
- \lambda \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\ 
0&1&0&0\\ 
0&0&1&0\\ 
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\right) = 0
$$
But since $A$ is symmetrical, I am wondering if there is a fast way to finding the eigenvalues, this is also because I was never taught how to find the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ matrix. If no short cuts, the how do you find the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ matrix?

"I was never taught how to find the determinant of a 4x4 matrix"  That seems like prerequisite knowledge that you should have learned long before being introduced to the concept of eigenvalues.  You should return to that.

There are typically two ways to define determinants that are useful for calculation purposes.  Leibniz's formula for determinants,  and Laplace Expansion.  It is also well known that if a matrix is deficient (not full rank) then it has determinant zero.

"Since $A$ is symmetrical..." A real matrix being symmetrical directly implies that the eigenvalues must also be real.  Apart from that however, I would not suggest thinking of a symmetric matrix as particularly being any easier to calculate the determinant of.

Surprised that Master Yoda never explained this...

"I was never taught how to find the determinant of a 4 x 4 matrix" now is the time to learn then. What makes it difficult for you?

This isn't just a symmetric matrix, it's a very particular type. So, firstly, you can use the fact there are a lot of zeros in it to make calculating the determinant easy (I assume you can do a 3x3 determinant; then you probably want to look at some examples of Laplace expansion). But given you haven't been taught 4x4 determinants, you might want to think about what transformation this matrix represents. Then see if you can work out the eigensystem without using determinants at all.

Along those lines, do you know eigen-vectors/values for $\pmatrix{1&0\0&1}?;$  What about $\pmatrix{0&1\1&0}?$

cut your matrix in sub-block matrices you will easily get $1$ with multiplicity $3$ and $-1$, plus it is diagonalisable in the basis $(e_1,e_2+e_3,e_2-e_3,e_4)$

$e_1,e_4$ are obvious eigenvectors (for the eigenvalue $1$). The plane spanned by $e_2,e_3$ is closed under $A$, so you are left with finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the restriction of $A$ to this plane.

@ChrisLewis Hi chris thanks for the comment, that is a really interesting comment. I think this is what I am looking for. by transformation, do you mean like rotational or other types? I thought you need to find the determinant to determine what type of transformation?

A is a permutation matrix
So corresponding permutation is
(1 2 3 4)
(1 3 2 4)
=(1)(2 3)(4)
Characteristics polynomial of A is (x-1)(x²-1)(x-1) =(x-1)³(x+1)
Eigen values are 1,1,1,-1 so detA= -1
